# Pass multiple URL parameters in Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, server, redirect

I'm trying to redirect www.example.com/page to www.example.com/something/some-stuff?foo=bar&foo2=bar2 in Nginx but can't seem to do it properly.

This is what I have so far:

```
server {
      listen          80;
      server_name     example.com
                      www.example.com;
      return ^/page /somepage/some-stuff?foo=bar&foo2=bar2 permanent;
}
```

What's wrong with the above server block?

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

```
location /page {
         rewrite ^/page http://$http_host/somepage/some-stuff?foo=bar&foo2=bar2 redirect;
        }
```